# JavaScript. Reference a variable that is created dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, for-loop

I have a for loop creating variables on the fly. Like score0, score1, score2 and so forth. The first part works like a charm. And score0, score1, score2 etc is created as I expect in this line:

```
this["score"+i] = 8;
```

The variables are created. Outside the loop i can log score[2] and it works.
However.

I can't seem to figure out how to reference the created variable inside of the for loop. I've tried some different options

Option 1:

```
arr = [1,2,3];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  this["score"+i] = 8;
  this["scorePercentage"+i] = this.score[i] * 10 / 100;
}
```

Option 2:

```
arr = [1,2,3];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  this["score"+i] = 8;
  this["scorePercentage"+i] = score[i] * 10 / 100;
}
```

How do I reference the created variable inside of the loop?

Thanks a bunch in advance.

Comment: why create variables like that instead of using an array or object?

Comment: Indeed. Use an array for this and save yourself some headaches in the future. It'll perform better as well.

Comment: creating numbered variables like this is an anti-pattern in JavaScript. Instead of asking about this specific code, can describe the specific problem you are trying to solve? – eg, *"how do I calculate scores and percentages based an array of values?"* – show input and expected output

Comment: access it the same way you define it : this["scorePercentage"+i] = this["score"+i] * 10 / 100;
}

Comment: @aorfevre how is that different than what Paul wrote (below) more than 5 mintues ago?

Comment: @naomik so far seems the same; haven't seen his reply as I opened the issue before he replied and added my response a bit later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use an array of objects with the wanted properties.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3],
    objects = array.map(function (value) {
        return {
            score: 8,
            percent: 8 * 10 % 100
        };
    });
    
console.log(objects);
```

or use an object directly with objects inside.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3],
    object = {};

array.forEach(function (value) {
    object[value] = {
        score: 8,
        percent: 8 * 10 % 100
    };
});
    
console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 2):

You just reference it the same way every time.

```
var arr = [1,2,3];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  this["score"+i] = 8;
  this["scorePercentage"+i] = this["score"+i] * 10 / 100;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that are wrong with your code

- You define variables like this: `score0`, `score1`, `score2` and then you try to reference a `score` array that was never created. `score1` is not the same as `score[1]`
- `arr` is never declared. That would cause problems if you ever have to run the code in strict mode
- You are defining the variables using `this`. Since you haven't included a tag that you're using a JS framework I'm going to assume that you are using vanilla JS. Using `this` to reference the `Window` object because if you ever refactor your code and put it inside a function and then run it in strict mode you will encounter errors. Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/53m8bfu9/)

Best way to do what you want to do is something like this:

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
var score = [];
var scorePercentage = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  score.push(8);
  scorePercentage.push( score[i] * 10 / 100 );
}
```